# Table from Excel to another table

Tags: excel

Suppose there are 3 columns. In 1 column number (a1), in the second name (b1), in the third description (c1). I want to make another 1 table, so that the data would spread to it, but with 1 condition. If in the 3 column, in one cell more than 500 characters, then continue to copy the data from the rows to the next cell. (For example, there is a line a2, b2, c2 In cell c2, 600 symbols are obtained, then the remaining characters are transferred to one cell, c3 and copy the text from cells a2, b2) Is it possible to trace it? To make, some counter, that he would count the symbols in the cell.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBTbl.png)

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQvpC.png)

[tabletest1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uTjk.png)

Comment: I think you need to give clear and crisp details to explain your problems

Comment: Made a screenshot, how to get it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i think this image will be self explanatory
[image: ![enter image description here]

First table contains your original data. Right upper one contains the results, and bottom one contains the formula

The formula `=IF((LEN(C2) > 5);MID(C2;6;500);" ")` checks the length of the text inside a cell, if its greater than 5 (you can modify this of course), then set the value of the cell to a substring (from 6th character) of the original text.

Comment: What is mid? Do I have an inscription in the cell name? (error)

Comment: MID is an excel function. It gets a text and returns a portion of it.
The prototype is `MID(text, initialPos, numOfChars)`
For instance, `MID(stackoverflow; 1; 5)` will return `stack` while
`MID(stackoverflow; 6, 100)` will return `overflow`

Note that the last argument is the number of chars to take, if there are less, it will takes what it can

Comment: Я сделал ту же таблицу, что и твоя. Но по какой-то причине я не заполняю данные. И появляется ошибка. А не все вроде разобрался.

Comment: Suppose we moved the remainder to the next cell. And how to do it, so that 2 cells will be reprinted again? This can be done?

Comment: It have been done in the image XD On the right-hand tables you have how to do it. The bottom table has the formulas that the upper one contains.

Comment: I guess I explained a little bit. I will have a large table, it will stretch to the bottom. And I need that the 2 table created by the same drag on the bottom. And of course the symbols moved not to the cell from the right, but 1 cell to the bottom. And accordingly the text from 2 other lines was repeated. Took a photo, about how to get it.

Comment: Made a screenshot, how to get it in the end.

Comment: Ok, i think what's the issue. You can play with the `IF(LEN(cell) > x)` function to duplicate the row with the remainder in 3rd column, but i think you finally need a macro

Comment: I can not write macros on vb. So if it does not complicate you, then I would not refuse to help. I, in principle, for this and indicated with #, maybe someone will help to realize this from there. Since I myself have been breaking my head for about 1.5 weeks on this issue and I have not got anything.

Comment: No problem. i'm trying a macro anyway. If i reach something i will share in another answer

Answer (score 0):

### VB Macro

After some tries, i got a VB macro which makes that

```
Sub copyTable()
    Dim colRange As Variant
    colRange = Array(1, 2, 3) 'Columns where your data is'
    Dim destColRange As Variant
    destColRange = Array(5, 6, 7) 'Columns where you want data be copied'
    n = UBound(colRange) - LBound(colRange)
    i = 2 'Initial row'
    newI = i
    maxLen = 10 'Maximum size allowed in one cell'
    While Not (Cells(i, colRange(0)) Is Nothing) And (Cells(i, colRange(0)) <> "")
        Text = Cells(i, colRange(n))
        Do
            For j = 0 To n - 1
                Cells(newI, destColRange(j)) = Cells(i, colRange(j))
            Next j
            Cells(newI, destColRange(j)) = Mid(Text, 1, maxLen)
            Text = Mid(Text, maxLen + 1)
            newI = newI + 1
        Loop Until Len(Text) <= 0
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

### Variables explanation

- *colRange*:     Indexes of columns with origin data
- *destColRange*: Indexes of columns where data will be written
- *i*:            Initial row
- *maxLen*:       Maximum length allowed per cell

**Note** that this snippet only cares about size of the **last** cell, if any other has more length it will copy them as they are.

when you run it you got something like
[image]

*I've never made a VB code, so don't be critic, it surely can be better*

Comment: Interesting. Now I'll try and write it off.

Comment: Можно еще вопрос. И как сделать проверку в vb, чтобы линии продолжали заполняться, если строки 1,2 были пустыми. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQvpC.png

Comment: Well, if you know how many rows you will procces, you can change the while loop with `While i < totalRows` where `totalRows` the **index** of the last row

Comment: If you do, as you said, then I continue to print the lines. But there are still gaps in the places where nothing originally existed.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uTjk.png

Comment: So, you want the gap between different row in result table too, right? Sorry, but Russian translation was so bad

Comment: If that's the case, take the `for` loop out from `do loop until` and put it right before (under `Text = Cells(i, colRange(n))`) line

Comment: Sorry, for bad english)

Comment: At me excel hangs, after this action.

Comment: For j = 0 To n - 1
                Cells(newI, destColRange(j)) = Cells(i, colRange(j))
            Next j
            Cells(newI, destColRange(j)) = Mid(Text, 1, maxLen)
            Text = Mid(Text, maxLen + 1)
            newI = newI + 1
            Text = Cells(i, colRange(n))
            Do
            Loop Until Len(Text) <= 0
        i = i + 1

Comment: `Next j` is the last instruction of `for` loop. Those 3 lines below must be inside `do` loop